# How to aggregate events across multiple sites in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I have several sites that I'm tracking on my Google Analytics account.  These sites all have the same events and event actions.

I'd like to generate a report for the same event action across all of my sites.

Can this be done right from the GA interface, and if so, how?

Comment: Are those domain sharing the same account? I mean the same UA-XXXXX-X id? otherwise you can't generate a custom report from differents accounts. You can create a custom report but it's going to be assigned to a concrete account

Comment: These sites are all on the same Analytics account, but all different UA codes.  It would be nice to be able to aggregate the same event across multiple sites, no?

Answer (score 1):

Your options are to export it into a format such as CSV and combine it, or integrate with the Analytics API and automatically query the results you want and combine them.

Another option is to follow the answer from this page which says https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/rQE8yGEFGuY/2FJLvNXz1nMJ

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%
3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {

   var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxx1-1"); // Master Account Account
   pageTracker._trackPageview();

   var secondTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxx2-1"); // Regional Account and Microsite
   secondTracker._trackPageview();

   var thirdTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxx2-2"); // Microsite only
   thirdTracker._setDomainName(".Your-Microsite-Domain-here.com"); // optional use of setDomainName element added as a precaution
   thirdTracker._trackPageview();

} catch(err){}
</script>

Note: you can also use include hostname filter to control traffic showin in profiles.
```